# How can I create a HashMap using Rayon's parallel fold?

Tags: rust, parallel-processing, fold, rayon

I am trying to create a `HashMap` using functional programming and utilizing parallelization by `rayon`.

If I try this without `rayon`, it works:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let nums = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2];
    let result: HashMap<i32, i32> =
        nums.iter()
            .filter(|x| *x % 2 == 0)
            .fold(HashMap::new(), |mut acc, x| {
                *acc.entry(*x).or_insert(0) += 1;
                acc
            });

    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

If I try to use multiple cores by switching from `iter()` to `par_iter()`, I get an error:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*; // 1.5.1
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let nums = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2];
    let result: HashMap<i32, i32> =
        nums.par_iter()
            .filter(|x| *x % 2 == 0)
            .fold(HashMap::new(), |mut acc, x| {
                *acc.entry(*x).or_insert(0) += 1;
                acc
            });

    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: expected a `Fn<()>` closure, found `HashMap<_, _>`
 --> src/main.rs:9:19
  |
9 |             .fold(HashMap::new(), |mut acc, x| {
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an `Fn<()>` closure, found `HashMap<_, _>`
  |
  = help: the trait `Fn<()>` is not implemented for `HashMap<_, _>`
  = note: wrap the `HashMap<_, _>` in a closure with no arguments: `|| { /* code */ }`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:7:9
   |
6  |       let result: HashMap<i32, i32> =
   |                   ----------------- expected due to this
7  | /         nums.par_iter()
8  | |             .filter(|x| *x % 2 == 0)
9  | |             .fold(HashMap::new(), |mut acc, x| {
10 | |                 *acc.entry(*x).or_insert(0) += 1;
11 | |                 acc
12 | |             });
   | |______________^ expected struct `HashMap`, found struct `Fold`
   |
   = note: expected struct `HashMap<i32, i32>`
              found struct `Fold<rayon::iter::Filter<rayon::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>, [closure@src/main.rs:8:21: 8:36]>, HashMap<_, _>, _>`
```

Obviously, Rust tries to stop me from doing something stupid involving race conditions, but how would I build a `HashMap` inside a `par_iter()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rayon's fold creates intermediate items (cannot be known how many). From the [documentation](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.fold) (emphasis mine):

> Parallel fold is similar to sequential fold except that the
> sequence of items may be subdivided before it is
> folded. Consider a list of numbers like `22 3 77 89 46`. If
> you used sequential fold to add them (`fold(0, |a,b| a+b)`,
> you would wind up first adding 0 + 22, then 22 + 3, then 25 +
> 77, and so forth. **The parallel fold works similarly except
> that it first breaks up your list into sublists, and hence
> instead of yielding up a single sum at the end, it yields up
> multiple sums. The number of results is nondeterministic, as
> is the point where the breaks occur.**

You need to reduce those intermediate items into the final one:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*; // 1.5.1
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let nums = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2];
    let result: HashMap<i32, i32> = nums
        .par_iter()
        .filter(|x| *x % 2 == 0)
        .fold(HashMap::new, |mut acc, x| {
            *acc.entry(*x).or_insert(0) += 1;
            acc
        })
        .reduce_with(|mut m1, m2| {
            for (k, v) in m2 {
                *m1.entry(k).or_default() += v;
            }
            m1
        })
        .unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=23b3039b14b95c6ad294a3747fdfd1a2)

Also note that the first parameter of Rayon's `fold` is a function that *creates the empty `HashMap`*, not an empty `HashMap` like the standard library's `fold`.

Comment: Also of note: the first parameter of rayon's `fold` is a function that creates the empty `HashMap`, not an empty `HashMap` like the std `fold`. Hence the absence of parentheses in your code.

Comment: @Jmb, yeah, forgot to mention that, thanks!. In the code is ok though.

Comment: I'd suggest to accumulate the values of `m1` in `m2` and return `m2` from the closure instead of taking the union of their keys and accumulating a new map

Comment: The reduction function can be severely simplified, see https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=23b3039b14b95c6ad294a3747fdfd1a2. This implementation can be further optimised by swapping `m1` and `m2` first if `m2` contains more elements, but I wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: @SvenMarnach yep, better reusing. Thanks!

Comment: Rayon's comments on reduce_with:
"This version of reduce is simple but somewhat less efficient. 
If possible, it is better to call reduce(), which requires an identity element." After small changes, see [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eb8aa277bd4f430860139a648620ae94)